# Нужно сделать так, чтобы при hover на блок A менялся только блок, к примеру, B или C

Tags: css3, jquery, javascript, html, css

```
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"> <div class="c"></div> </div>
```

Собственно, файл стиля

```
.a:hover=.c{background:red}
```

Не знаю поймете ли вы то, что тут написано, в общем под знаком "=" я имел ввиду, что если навести мышь на блок A блок C станет красным, не зависимо от дочерности (расположения этого дива (ну или если блок C расположен так, как написано в коде свыше))

Вот есть ли селектор в CSS который реализует такую возможность?)) Но желательно очень только CSS

Без javascript и вытекающих (я их пока не знаю)

Ну, если же без них никак не получится это реализовать, был бы очень благодарен за шаблонный код, который эту функцию реализует)) И, если не трудно, напишите хоть вкратце куда и что вставлять)) Ибо в javascript я ноль))

Спасибо огромное)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот](http://jsfiddle.net/LgxUh/) пример, в котором используются только стили.

```css
div {
  widt: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.a:hover + .b .c {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">a</div>
<div class="b">b
  <div class="c">c</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо просто наиогромнейшее!! Сделал именно то, что нужно благодаря вашему примеру!!
А то я все тильдой ~ пытался сделать, но она только дочерние элементы воспринимает

Спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b">
    <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

Для данного случая селектор будет таким:

```
.a:hover + .b .c {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Или более строгий вариант:

```
.a:hover + .b > .c {
   background-color: red;
}
```

[Да-да, средствами CSS тут не обойтись!](http://jsbin.com/oTAgOYij/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Так можно? А я тут стараюсь..)

Можно я поправлю? `.a:hover + .b > .c {
   background-color: red;
}` Точки в стилях забыли.

Comment: @Отоно Как
А если 
<div id="q"></div>
<div id="a">
 <div id="b">
  <div id="c"></div>
 </div>
</div>
И нужно, нажав на q изменить c?

Comment: Верно подмечено. Добавил заодно ссылку на jsbin.

Comment: @Soulism Вот решение для второго случая http://jsbin.com/ImihIDe/1/edit?html,css,output